# Java File Creation Filecount limit

Tags: java, unix

i want to ask if there is a limit for how many files can be in a directory?

I write files with

```
File outputFile = new File("xy.txt");
outputFile.createNewFile();
```

and i got following Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1043) ~[na:na]
    ...
```

The folder contains more than 1.7 million files, after clearing the folder the exception disapears.

When i create files manually (ssh to the host) I have no problems creating files.

Comment: What OS? what FileSystem? On Linux (shared/virtual vm?), maybe you run our of inodes..?!

Comment: After getting this exception, you can still create files manually?

Comment: It could be that the java implementation is more constrained than your actual specific underlying file system. But wondering, why do you have so many files? ;-)

Comment: OS is Red Hat. The filesystem is a mounted cifs....

Answer (score 1):

The various operating systems and their flavours have all different limits for the number of files per folder/directory, and also for the number of files per file system and/or drive.

In addition, some operating systems or extensions to an operating system allow to impose a user quota for the number of files, again per directory/folder and/or per file system.

So the answer to your question is a clear yes.

For some operating systems/flavours, these numbers are configurable within some limitations (for file systems, usually a reformatting is necessary).

But as said, this is a limitation of the underlying OS, and nothing special for Java.

Comment: It might be possible that the Java implementation has constraints such as "ensure it works on *any* Unix system", so Java allows for less files, compared to you doing it manually via ssh.